# XPath "in" operator

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-1.0

Is there is an operator in XPath 1.0 that acts as "in" operator in SQL?

```
select * from tbl_students where id in (1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The = operator of XPath 1.0 works that way, though XPath 1.0 doesn't provide syntax for writing sequences.  So if you have an XML document of the form

```
<doc>
  <value>1</value>
  <value>2</value>
  <value>3</value>
</doc>
```

then an expression like `//doc[value = 2]` will return that `doc` element.

In XPath 2.0, the syntax `(1, 2, 3)` will create a sequence of three integers, and you can write conditions like `$i = (1, 2, 3)`.  But literal sequences are not a feature of XPath 1.0 -- the only way to get multiple values on one side of an XPath expression is to use a path expression that matches multiple nodes.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, the above answer is right. To make it more clear, in Xpath this will look something like:

```
//*:document[*:documentType=("magazine","newspaper")]
```

wich would be the equivalant of:

```
select * from documents where documenttype in ('newsletter','magazine')
```

Comment: Just to complement another example: You can use `.=("abc", "bcd")` for check if current node value is one of the specified strings.

Comment: It should be noted that this syntax relies on Xpath 2.0, the question is tagged as xpath 1.0; this answer is not helpful to me personally. I ended up simply making repeated templates using a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

To find out if the 'id' you search is in the sequence of (1, 2, 3, 4)
[index-of()](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-index-of) might be a choice. 
Pay attention it returns list of indexes.

For a document part like

```
<student id='1'/>
<student id='101'/>
<student id='1001'/>
```

Select will something like

```
//*[not(empty(index-of((1, 2, 3, 4), @id)))]
```

Comment: I upvoted this, but this answer is Xpath 1.0, unfortunately, I can no longer downvote this, as would be appropriate. Sorry.

Comment: The above comment is misleading. To be clear, `index-of()` is not available in Xpath 1.0.