# XPath: how to select nodes by IN condition?

Tags: xpath

Is it possible to select nodes in a similar way?

```
'./tr[position() in (1, 3, 7)]'
```

I found only this solution:

```
'./tr[position() = 1 or position() = 3 or position() = 7]'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [XPath "in" operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13871250/xpath-in-operator)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In XPath 2.0 you would simply do:

```
./tr[position = (1,3,7)]
```

In XPath 1.0 the usual way to do it is the solution you already found, an alternative that is a bit shorter would be something like:

```
./tr[contains('1 3 7', position())]
```

The spaces in the string are essential here, otherwise you'd also get nodes 13,37 and 137.