# how to use operator " in " in xpathin selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

if link : l = link.get_attribute("href") print (l)  button=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath( "//button[@id = 'refuse-alert-button' and @data-record " in l +"]")

bug ////////////////////////////////////  File "D:\project\odoo_selenium\api\frontend.py", line 233, in refuse_record "//button[@id = 'refuse-alert-button' and @data-record " in l +"]")

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Please try to format your question more reasonably.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPath "in" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13871250/xpath-in-operator)

Comment: ^ according to the linked question, the `in` operator is available in XPath 2.0. Selenium only supports XPath 1.0. There is probably another way to do this. Please edit your question and add more details such as the relevant HTML and what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

What i understood is you want to get element which is matching with the attribute you want to pass in xpath.

```
//button[@id = 'refuse-alert-button' and @data-record ='" + l + "']

l = link.get_attribute("href") 
    print (l)  
button=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath( "//button[@id = 'refuse-alert-button' and @data-record ='" + l + "']")
```

In your case

You can use `contains` though if want partial match

```
//button[@id = 'refuse-alert-button' and contains(@data-record,'" + l + "')]
```